# Angular material md-radio-button in table tr repeat

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-material

I am unable to use `md-radio-button` properly within `tr` repeat, is there any way to use it without `md-radio-group` or placing `md-radio-group` above the `tr`, so that it will be same for all rows in table.

```
<form form-submit action="">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="data in data2">
        <td>
    <md-radio-group ng-model="test">
      <md-radio-button  value="{{data.name}}" aria-label="Label {{data.id}}"></md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>
        </td>
        <td>{{data.id}}</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
    <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised">Submit</md-button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the md-radio-group input breaks  tags. You can still fake it in CSS by wrapping the radio button in a  and applying display:table row

```
       <table>
        <md-radio-group ng-model="test" class="md-primary">
          <div ng-click="setSelect(data.name)" style="display:table-row" ng-repeat="data in data2">
            <md-radio-button ng-value="data.name">
              {{data.id}}
            </md-radio-button>
          </div>
        </md-radio-group>
      </table>
```

md-radio-group also seems to mess up  tags, so a simple function called with ng-click on the  wrapping the button takes care of that

```
 $scope.setSelect = function(modelVal){
    $scope.test=modelVal;
 }
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/clonardo/pen/BNEjKp)

Answer (score 2):

Why you want to use it "without `md-radio-group`"? Repeating `md-radio-group` inside every `td` element is totally fine.

See this [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/M4sTaL?p=preview)